# Three values for a for loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I would like to have three values increment at different speeds. My overall goal is to emulate this pattern:

```
0,0,   0
0,1,   1
0,2,   2
1,0,   3
1,1,   4
1,2,   5
2,0,   6
2,1,   7
2,2,   8
```

The first two numbers are easy. I would solve it like this:

```
for x in range(3):
    for y in range(3):
        print(x, y)
>>> 0 0
>>> 0 1
>>> 0 2
>>> 1 0
>>> 1 1
>>> 1 2
>>> 2 0
>>> 2 1
>>> 2 2
```

This is the pattern that I want.

The question is how do I increment the third number by one each time, while still having the first two numbers increment in the way that they are?

Basically, how can I make the third number increment by one each time the for loop goes?

Comment: Why not keep track of the count in a variable `count`?

Comment: initialize `n` to 0, then `n = n+1` in the inner loop. Not the only way, but why complicate things when a simple counter will do just as nicely?

Comment: @BryanOakley how could I make a counter?

Comment: @MattX you can assign `count = 0` at the beginning of your code and update this value wherever you need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since we have all these answers, I will post the most straightforward one

```
count = 0
for x in range(3):
    for y in range(3):
        print(x, y, count)
        count += 1
```

Comment: Oh okay I tried implementing this into my code and I see where I made the mistake @RafaelC

Answer (score 5):

You don't need nested loops for this. You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to get your first two numbers, and [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to get your last one.

```
from itertools import product

for i, (u, v) in enumerate(product(range(3), repeat=2)):
    print(u, v, i)
```

**output**

```
0 0 0
0 1 1
0 2 2
1 0 3
1 1 4
1 2 5
2 0 6
2 1 7
2 2 8
```

---

`itertools.product` is a very handy function. It basically performs nested loops efficiently, but its main benefit is that they don't *look* nested, so you don't end up with massively indented code. However, its real strength comes when you don't know how many nested loops you need until runtime.

`enumerate` is probably even more useful: it lets you iterate over a sequence or any iterable and returns the iterable's items as well as an index number. So whenever you need to loop over a list but you need the list items and their indices as well, it's more efficient to use `enumerate` to get them both at once, rather than having a loop that uses `range` to produce the index and then using the index to fetch the list item.

Comment: While this is a great example of some fancy python features, for a beginner I think this is a much less readable solution than a simple counter.

Comment: @BryanOakley Fair point. I agree that `product` might be a little bit advanced for a beginner. That's why I felt it was appropriate to add the links to the docs & some explanation about it to my answer. OTOH, it's never too early to learn about `enumerate`, IMHO.

Comment: True, but I mentioned using a counter in a comment, and the OP response was "how could I make a counter?", so this is a _very_ inexperienced programmer.

Answer (score 5):

The third number counts how many total iterations you had so far. For each increment in X it gains the total size of Y's loop, and to that you need to add the value of Y:

```
X_SIZE = 3
Y_SIZE = 3
for x in range(X_SIZE):
    for y in range(Y_SIZE):
        print(x, y, x * Y_SIZE + y)
```

Comment: This is not the right answer because it doesn't work on every range and every step.

Answer (score 3):

single variable. single loop.

```
for i in range(9):
  print(i // 3, i % 3, i)
```

`//` is floor division and `%` is modulus (the remainder, in most cases)

Personally, I like this solution because it plainly explains the underlying pattern, and can therefore be easily altered or extended to other patterns.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
for x in range(3):
    for y in range(3):
        print(x, y, x * 3 + y) # Python 3.x
        print x, y, x * 3 + y # Python 2.x
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This works but only if your `range` starts at 0 and has no steps

Comment: BTW, you can (& should) use the `print` function in Python 2.6+, you just need  `from __future__ import print_function` at the top of your script, before other `import` statements. That makes it easier to migrate to Python 3. However, the Python 2.6 version doesn't support all the latest `print` function features.

Answer (score 1):

You can use simply a count variable for this

```
count = 0
for x in range(3):
    for y in range(3):
        print(x, y, ' ' ,count) # use ' ' for making exact look what OP asked..lol
        count = count + 1
```

Comment: @RafaelC I'm sorry, but when I posted my answer then I saw you already gave something like that and also noticed that you didn't print the count and then edited.  I hope it's clear to you now.

Comment: @RafaelC Again you might already posted your answer while I'm typing. I upvote your answer too like others. :)

Answer (score 1):

This looks more natural to me :)

```
x_range = 3  
y_range = 3  
for x in range( x_range*y_range ):  
    print(x // x_range, x % x_range, x)
```

Similar to what cwharris wrote.